# Python version and performance in ML

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, memory

I couldn't find any answer on that question, but does Python version really matter when you implement different ML models (like catboost or xgboost) or NN (like pytorch). I do know that these models were written on C++ and other programming languages and my question may sound quite trivial, but does it really matter to upgrade Python version to increase performance and use less Memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Python has minimal impact on performance relative to other factors (e.g., model architecture, framework choice, data size, and the number of epochs). Being concerned about the Python version is an example of premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't know that it doesn't really matter